# String Parsing in VBScript using a marker variable

Tags: vbscript

I had a big chunk of tab limited data to be filtered out and I could able to do it using VBSCRIPT.

In my current file I have below stated data.

```
abcd9
efgh9
12349
0x11111
11111
22222
33333
44444
0x11112
55555
66666
77777
88888
0x11113
```

.
.
.

My result should be

```
{
11111,
22222
}
{
33333,
44444
}
{
55555,
66666
}
{
77777,
88888
}
```

This has been a pretty difficult task any solutions would be very much appreciated.

Where  0x11111,  0x11112,  0x11113 are the marker variables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you always have exactly 4 lines between 2 markers? Are the data lines always numbers of 5 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sample data is representative, use a grouped regular expression:

```
  Dim sAll   : sAll       = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\17050037.txt").ReadAll
  Dim rePair : Set rePair = New RegExp
  rePair.Global    = True
  rePair.Multiline = True
  rePair.Pattern   = "^(\d+)\r\n^(\d+)\r\n"
  Dim oMTS   : Set oMTS   = rePair.Execute(sAll)
  Dim oMt
  For Each oMT IN oMTS
    WScript.Echo "{"
    WScript.Echo oMT.SubMatches(0) & ","
    WScript.Echo oMT.SubMatches(1)
    WScript.Echo "}"
  Next
```

output:

```
{
11111,
22222
}
{
33333,
44444
}
{
55555,
66666
}
{
77777,
88888
}
```

**ADDED:**

If you prefer a line loop, try:

```
Dim file  : Set file = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\17050037.txt")
Dim state : state = 0
Do Until file.AtEndOfStream
  Dim Line : Line = file.ReadLine
  Select Case state
    Case 1, 3
      WScript.Echo "{"
      WScript.Echo Line & ","
      state = state + 1
    Case 2, 4
      WScript.Echo Line
      WScript.Echo "}"
      state = state + 1
    Case Else
      If "0x" = Left(Line, 2) Then state = 1
  End Select
Loop
file.Close
```